# How can I force the update the view of a Hosted Feature Layer View that has a dependent view in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, json, hosted-feature-layer

**Problem**

I have added two fields to the hosted layer ("fire_hydrant") and need to update the two associated views to reflect these changes. However, one view is a view of the first view, creating a dependency that the AGOL gui will not let me update with.

**I Have:**

- fire_hydrant (hosted layer)
- hydrantviewing_edit (hosted layer view)
- Hydrant Last Inspection (hosted layer, view

In this order, the layers are parent, child, grandchild views. "Hydrant Last Inspection" is a view/joined table created from hydrantviewing_edit. Both layers are confirmed in their definition as `"isUpdateableView" : true`. However, I am unable to update "hydrantviewing_edit" from the item details page gui - the option is grayed out with a message `"You can't modify view layers with dependent tile layers, vector tile layers, or view layers."` (this is pictured). Alternatively, the "Hydrant Last Inspection" layer does not even show an update view option... [image]

**I have attempted:**

I have attempted to manually update the service definition through admin in POST. Though, I receive the following error: [image]